# Add 2 hours to current time in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Which is the valid syntax of this query in MySQL?

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (now() + 2 hours) > start_time
```

*note: start_time is a field of courses table*

Answer (score 397, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > start_time
```

See [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for other date/time manipulation.

Answer (score 52):

You need [DATE_SUB()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) OR [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Comment: If only there were examples.

Answer (score 34):

```
SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > start_time
```

Answer (score 29):

The [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function will do the trick. (You can also use the [ADDTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function if you're running at least v4.1.1.)

For your query, this would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) > start_time
```

Or,

```
SELECT * 
FROM courses 
WHERE ADDTIME(now(), '02:00:00') > start_time
```

Comment: If only there were examples.

Comment: The documentation has some good examples (and SO is not meant to be a replacement for the documentation).. But in the interest of this question and future visitors, I have added both syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work

```
SELECT NAME 
FROM GEO_LOCATION
WHERE MODIFY_ON BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND SYSDATE()
```