# mySQL query for selecting time periods

Tags: mysql

I have a timestamp field and I want to select * where time [is within the last 24 hours]

What is the correct query for this?

Comment: Here's a simple example with 2 hours. Extending this to 24 is trivial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where `time` between date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and now();
```

Comment: I see what you mean. The example I posted was using date_add and hours.

Comment: **YES** the answer won't be make use of any index (if there is an index built on time field

Comment: That's a cool query, thanks. Can I use other keywords for interval, such as hour, min, week etc?

Comment: yes, you can refer to the available unit http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add