# Mysql DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 24 hours or weekday?

Tags: mysql, date, sql-date-functions

I am trying to get the total amount of registered users per day. At the moment I am using this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, email FROM users WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) < lastModified"
```

But I am not sure if this works per day or per 24 hours?

For example, a user who registered 22 hours ago shouldn't be returned. I just want the user of today(=Tuesday).

Comment: Please see this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql

Answer (score 33):

lastModified is, presumably, a datetime.  To convert this into a date you can simply wrap it in DATE() i.e. `DATE(lastModified)`. `DATE()` returns the date part of a datetime value which is effectively 00:00 on that day.

```
SELECT
    name,
    email
FROM users
WHERE DATE(lastModified) = DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) )
```

Using this to match a `WHERE` though would be inefficient as all rows would require DATE applied to them and so it would probably scan the whole table.  It is more efficient to compare `lastModified` to the upper and lower bounds you are looking for, in this case >= 00:00 on `SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)` and < 00:00 on `NOW()`

Therefore you can use BETWEEN to make your select giving the following.

```
SELECT
    name,
    email
FROM users
WHERE lastModified 
    BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) )
    AND DATE ( NOW() )
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you need

```
SELECT
    name,
    email
FROM users
WHERE DATE(lastModified) = DATE( NOW() )
```

This effectively "rounds to the date only" and will therefore only match records "since midnight".