# SQL Query Current Date Minus 180 days?

Tags: sql, radix, libreoffice

Query
I'm getting a syntax error:

```
SELECT "LastFilterDate" 
FROM "Filter Cartridge Updates" 
WHERE "Filter Cartridge Updates"."LastFilterDate" < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 180 DAY)
```

I want to select the LastFilterDateS that are older than the current date minus 180 days (6 months).

I'm using LibreOffice base.

error in question:

> SQL Status: HY000 Error code: 1000
>
> syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting BETWEEN or IN or
>   SQL_TOKEN_LIKE

Sandesh gave a fantastic link on the subject, but I'm still getting a syntax error.
variations I've tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Filter Cartridge Updates 
WHERE LastFilterDate BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 180 DAY ) ) AND DATE ( NOW() )


SELECT * 
FROM "Filter Cartridge Updates" 
WHERE "Filter Cartridge Updates"."LastFilterDate" BETWEEN DATE( DATE_SUB( NOW() , INTERVAL 180 DAY ) ) AND DATE ( NOW() )
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: Oh dear, I should have mentioned: When I run this in LibreOffice Base I get a syntax error.

Comment: Can you include the exact text of the error please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633653/mysql-date-subnow-interval-1-day-24-hours-or-weekday

Comment: Not sure what DBMS engine is behind LibreOffice, but in standard SQL you would use `current_date - interval '180' day`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using MYSQL syntax for an SQL that is not MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some help on the LibreOffice website. I found this: =DATEDIF("1974-04-17";"2012-06-13";"d") which yields the number of days between 2 dates.

So you could change your where clause to be (if this allows substitution - you'll have to test that), to:

Where =DATEDIF(last_filter_date,current_date;"d") > 180

Note: I only put stubs in for the dates, you'll have to format those correctly.