# Mysql update database where date == -15 from current

Tags: php, mysql

i've been looking around for a way to do this; I found one tutorial that suggested using the dateadd (which i found out is date_add in mysql) function... but I've had no luck with that.

I need to have something that updates the database every 15 minutes or so via a Cronjob... The cron job is already set up (Php file), but i cannot get the DB to update every fifteen minutes.

anyway, this is the code i've got currently--i was really stressing out trying to figure out how to get it to work... so i know what i'm doing doesn't actually work.

```
 UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner, death = 'off', wifi = 'on' WHERE underSiege = 1 AND siegeStart = (current_timestamp)-15
```

I've also tried doing this

```
$date=date('-15 minutes'); $sql = "UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner, death = 'off', wifi = 'on' WHERE underSiege = 1 AND siegeStart = ".$date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.-

```
<?php
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 minutes'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here, how to deal with times using MySQL

[Add 2 hours to current time in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
 DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `siegeStart` of `datetime` or `timestamp` data type then

Use

```
siegeStart = ( current_timestamp - interval 15 minute )
```

in the update statement.

But the update will only work if the `seconds` part of the `siegeStart` also matches.

If you can omit `seconds` part of your date, then

Use

```
date_format( siegeStart, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' ) = 
date_format( current_timestamp - interval 15 minute, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i' )
```

**Refer To**:

- [***INTERVAL clause: INTERVAL expr unit***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
- [***DATE_FORMAT(date,format)***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 0):

The current time minus 15 minutes can be represented by the two functions CURTIME and SUBTIME:

SUBTIME(CURTIME(),'00:15:00.0');

So, based on your posted statement, the modified version is:

UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner, death = 'off', wifi = 'on' WHERE underSiege = 1 AND siegeStart =SUBTIME(CURTIME(),'00:15:00.0')

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you have been looking for:

```
UPDATE starinformation SET starOwner = nextOwner, death = 'off', wifi = 'on' WHERE underSiege = 1 AND siegeStart = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Here `DATE_SUB` subtracts the given date `NOW()` with given `INTERVAL`.