# How to add 2 hours to TIME type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How can I add two hours to the mysql field of `TIME` type? This problem seems unsolvable to me. I have tried:

1)

```
select TimeStart + interval 2 hour
from table
```

returns null

2)

```
select addtime(TimeStart, interval 2 hour)
from table
```

returns error

3)

```
select convert_tz(TimeStart, 'GMT', 'CEST')
from table
```

(because the 2 hour difference was due to messed up timezones, so this is another way to correct it)

also returns null!

4)

```
select date_add(TimeStart, interval 2 hour)
from table
```

also returns null!

I start to curse mysql... [would be easy with DATETIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/589652/684229), but really not very easy to work with the TIME type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I just figured it out!

```
addtime(TimeStart, '2:00')
```

Not very intuitive and consistent with the `INTERVAL` thing though!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT HOUR(TimeStart)+2 FROM table
```

gives you the 2 hour increment.