# How to add 1 HOUR in last activity date and time

Tags: php, mysql

here's my SQL data  .. How to add 1 Hour on the last activity. That after updating it will be 2015-05-01  20:24:42 ? Thank you

```
 lastActivity   
 2015-05-01 19:24:42
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Here's a [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql) article showing how it's done... assuming that is an actual date time data type

Answer (score 0):

U can use the SQL function DATEADD

```
DATEADD(hh, 1, last_activity)
```

Example query:

```
SELECT user_id, DATEADD(hh, 1,last_activity) AS new_activity_date FROM users
```

Comment: can i ask question if how to query lastActivity that exactly 1hr from now..  for example i have in my database 2015-05-01 19:46:59    and 2015-05-01 21:42:21   so the output must be 1 only, which is 2015-05-01 19:46:59 because its in the range if you add 1 hour from now..

Comment: I'm not sure if i get you question right but if i do the answer is: DATEADD(hh, 1, now()) AS new_activity_date. This will add 1 hour to the current time.

Comment: yes I already add 1 hr from lastActivty..  So my question now if u know how to query users that active 1hour exact from the current time.. for my example..  i have two users which is  2015-05-01 19:46:59    and 2015-05-01 21:42:21   the difference is 2hrs   so i how can i query user for example the time is 2015-05-01 19:47:59  so 1hr from the 2015-05-01 21:42:21 is not in the range so it will not be query.. only the 2015-05-01 19:46:59