# MySQL : Converting Strings AM to PM

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

i have a column of Strings like `2015/10/14 07:00:00` i need to convert them to DateTime, my problem is :

07:00 is in **pm time**

i need to get that in a format of **19:00**

my code:

```
UPDATE `DATE_tests`
      SET `newDate` = STR_TO_DATE(`oldDate`, '%Y/%m/%d %r')
```

to be precise i need `2015/10/14 07:00:00` to be `2015-10-14 19:00:00`.

i can get so far `2015-10-14 07:00:00`

Comment: Use `%H` instead of `%r`.  The formats are very well documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format.

Comment: @gordon-linoff i did Use %H instead of %r and still same result

Comment: How do you know it's 19:00 and not 7:00 if there's no AM/PM?

Comment: @dnoeth i scraped the data from a website and all the data are pm's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fix the table and store dates as *dates*, not as strings.  But you need to add 12 hours to do what you want.  Something like this

```
UPDATE `DATE_tests`
      SET `newDate` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`oldDate`, '%Y/%m/%d %r'), interval 12 hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: i got this error `SQL syntax; ... near 'hours), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')'`

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2015/10/14 07:00:00', '%Y/%m/%d %r'), interval 12 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') @MounirElfassi

Comment: ok i found the error in`interval 12 hours)` it should be `interval 12 hour)` whit no s. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try:`INTERVAL 12 HOUR`

```
UPDATE `DATE_tests`
      SET `newDate` = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(`oldDate`, '%Y/%m/%d %r'), INTERVAL 12 HOUR), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

see here:[Add 2 hours to current time in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql)