# How to update datetime by +15 hours with MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table containing a datetime column.

I need to add 15 hours to all these values.

e.g.

```
As Is: 2007-08-22 08:55:10  
To Be: 2007-08-22 23:55:10

As Is: 2009-08-22 14:55:10  
To Be: 2009-08-23 05:55:10
```

Is there a MySQL `UPDATE` query that can do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add 2 hours to current time in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql)

Comment: There are already questions on how to add a time interval in mysql

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Given that `test` is the table, `date_col` is the column with the date to be updated and `id` is the primary key of the `test` table:

```
update test set date_col = ADDTIME(date_col, '15:0:0') where id=1;
```

tested with mysql version 5.5.4

Answer (score 8):

```
update table_name set column_name =DATE_ADD(column_name, INTERVAL 15 HOUR)
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.

Comment: The DATE_ADD() function adds a specified time interval to a date. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

update table_name set column_name = ADDTIME(column_name, '15:0:0');