# MYSQL select data 12 hours before expire

Tags: mysql

I have data in Mysql

```
oder_id | exp
1111    | 2020-05-06 21:00:01
```

Can you help me, I want select data 12 hours before expire from now. Thanks guys

Comment: ```WHERE `exp` < NOW() - INTERVAL 12 HOUR``` (or `>`, or `+`, or ...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add 2 hours to current time in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589652/add-2-hours-to-current-time-in-mysql)

Comment: its `>` for the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should work:**

select * from yourTable where HOUR(TIMEDIFF(now(),exp)) < 12

Comment: @Akina comment however will get better performance provided `exp` is indexed. Compare the `EXPLAIN {query}` ouputt of both (or just measure the time).